# How to select/deselect all checkboxes in a certain row in excel if there are other checkboxes in the worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Since I already have a button for all the checkboxes in the worksheet, I want to assign a button for each column that will select and deselect all the checkbox in that column.

This is what I did for Selecting all the checkboxes in the worksheet and it worked

```
Dim cb As CheckBox

For Each cb In ActiveSheet.Checkboxes

    If cb.Name <> ActiveSheet.Checkboxes("Check Box 69").Name Then
        cb.Value = ActiveSheet.Checkboxes("Check Box 69").Value
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkboxes have a `TopLeftCell` property which you can use:

```
Sub TT()

    Dim cb As CheckBox, cb69 As CheckBox

    Set cb69 = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 69")

    For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes

        If cb.TopLeftCell.Column = 3 And cb.Name <> cb69.Name Then
            cb.Value = cb69.Value
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```